# I'm trying to create a speak app but i got error as Segmentation fault

Tags: python, pypdf, pyttsx, espeak

I'm trying to build text speaking app with Python. Here this is my code:

```
import pyttsx3
import PyPDF2
book=open("LifesAmazingSecets.pdf",'rb')
pdfReader=PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(book)
pages=pdfReader.numPages
print(pages)
engine = pyttsx3.init()
page=pdfReader.getPage(155)
text=page.extractText()
engine.say(text)
engine.runAndWait()
```

I'm trying to run this code but I get this error:

```
Segmentation fault
```

What is ***Segmentation fault***  and how do I recover from it?

Comment: It would be helpful if you identify which line is causing the segmentation fault.

Comment: This is what a segmentation fault is: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2346806/6486738. However, it's not something that's going to help you in this case. You've probably used the library wrong or there's a bug in it.